# How to use jquery to add list items into <ul> dynamically with php in side?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically add li into ul from the database.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to .append() php functions through jQuery.

Here's my current code.

```
 <ul id="ulBox"></ul>

  <script>
   var html = '<li style="padding-left:20px;">'  +
  '<a href="<?php echo base_url().'public_profile/user/'.$attendees[$i]['user_id']?>">' + 
  '</a>'+ 
  ' <img src="<?php echo base_url(). 'uploads/'.$attendees[$i]['image_key'];?>"/>'+ 
  '<p><?php echo $attendees[$i]['fullname'];?>'+
  '</p>'+
  '</li>'

         for (var j=0, j<<?php $attendees[$i];?>, j++){
            $('#ulBox').append(html);
          }
  </script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you able to console.log your atendees? Have you made an AJAX call somewhere?

Comment: @BravoZulu No, I haven't used AJAX before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, and please, stop meddling php with javascript,
Try this code

```
<ul id="ulBox">
    <?php

        // I'm assuming $attendees is an array of your data
        for ($j=0; $j<count($attendees); $j++){
            $html = '<li style="padding-left:20px;">'
                .'<a href="'. base_url() .'public_profile/user/'. $attendees[$j]['user_id'] .'"></a>'
                .'<img src="'. base_url() .'uploads/'. $attendees[$j]['image_key'] .'"/>'
                .'<p>'. $attendees[$j]['fullname'] .'</p>'
                .'</li>';

            echo($html);
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

This is basic and should keep you going for now. Add comment if you find anything challenging.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You are right, I should just use php! One question though, after implementing the code, the ul is also recreated multiple times according to the loop. I'm not sure why it does that.

Comment: Check out the code with more detail. I didn't put the `ul` tag inside any loop. Put the `ul` outside all your loops.

Comment: Thank you Oniya Daniel, it's solved. I had another php loop outside this function. After I get rid of that loop. It works. Thanks again